# Visual Studio 2008 HTML auto-formatter

Tags: html, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

Visual Studio 2008 "auto-formats" any block line elements such as `div`, `h1`, etc. using a line break after the opening tag.

This has always bothered me when it comes to `h1`, `h2` etc. I pretty much always have them on a single line. Is there any way to configure Visual Studio to keep these on one line?

I.e. this is what it does

```
<h1>
    This is a header</h1>
```

This is what I want:

```
<h1>This is a header</h1>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you go into Tools | Options | Text Editor | HTML | Format | Tag Specific Option then you will be able to set your own settings - rather than that i don't believe there is a simple way of controlling this

please correct me if i am wrong